# what is the most efficient way of reading a log file in java?

Tags: java, logging, file-io

What is the most efficient(fast and safe) way of reading a log file in java? The log file continuously(almost every second)  gets updated.

Comment: What kind of a log file? Web server logs?

Comment: yes exactly, to be precise its the tomcats accesslog file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Apache JMeter (open source, friendly licensing) has some [classes that you may be able to reuse](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/util/accesslog/TCLogParser.html) which parse Tomcat access logs. Internally, these classes are used in JMeter for the [Access Log Sampler](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/jmeter_accesslog_sampler_step_by_step.pdf) which is a tool that simulates production traffic in development environments by parsing access logs and generating HTTP requests to a development web server based on the logs. You can probably reuse just the log parsing functionality for your own purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky, and depends on many variables, but you might want to take a look at BufferedReader and see if does what you need.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about server logs then you might want to look at an existing tool like [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I've had really good luck with [Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to follow the output the "tail -f foobar.log" works well.  If you are on a Windows machine, it is available with Cygwin.  http://www.cygwin.com/.

Comment: Thanks, But i am looking for a solution which specifically uses java

Comment: In that case please elaborate on precisely what functionality you expect.  Watching a log file scroll by?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tail a particular file, you can look at [Tailer](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html). This class will work both for windows and *nix systems. You should be careful while reading a file in windows, because most of the log rotation programs, would try to rename the file. If you hold a lock on that file, the renaming would fail.

If you are looking at managing a directory with log files, this would be a good thing to look for [Most efficient way to tail/poll a log file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118264/most-efficient-way-to-tail-poll-a-log-file-in-java/15122236#15122236)