# Most efficient way to tail/poll a log file in Java

Tags: java, performance, file, file-io, polling

There are many approaches, one could use create a Program and just call the Unix `tail` command, however the problem with this is that the process must be installed on a Unix machine with tail installed.

The other option is to just read the file, line by line until there are no more lines, sleep for a period of time and then try to read the next line and repeat.

The question is what/how do I go about polling a file which is actively being written to. AFAIK there is no way in Java to get async notifications when a file has been modified as this is too low level (something that comes from the OS). I am also aware of no libs which support this.

I was thinking a better approach may be to sleep/poll on the modified date of a file..?

Any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use Java 7 there are File Watchers and you could implement what you need.
[File Notifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

For Java 6 (and previous) you would have to use Apache Commons VFS ([File Monitor)](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/impl/DefaultFileMonitor.html) lib to create your own file watcher.

If you can't go to Java 7 or use third party libs (e.g commons or [jnotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/)) you would have to write a file watchdog your self using polling threads.

Comment: I suspect File Notifications is only for adding and removing entries. There is an ENTRY_MODIFY but I thought it was only changes to the directory entry rather than file length.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [java nio's WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to get asynchronous notifications if a file/directory has changed. This [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) explains the way to use it.

Comment: Java 7, cant use it in this case but good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to simplify this is to create a Thread which poll the size of the file and only reads that much i.e. it never reaches the end as such.  This data read can be written to a pipe allowing your main thread to read a continous pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know answer. Just two tips
1. Maybe RandomAccessFile would help you.
2. Try find another open source program, which do this. (e.g. IntelliJ IDEA do exactly this)