# Monitoring a File in Java

Tags: java, performance, file

Im reading a log file in Java on a Linux box on a continual schedule of 2 minutes looking for certain messages. I store the last offset (RandomAccessFile getFilePointer) and read from it onwards when I detect LastModified has changed; is this best practice or even right?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118264/most-efficient-way-to-tail-poll-a-log-file-in-java

Comment: Yip - but no real clarity on solution on approach. Lots of suggestions on third party tools and Java 7, but is the approach I use above correct if I implement it myself this way....

Comment: Good point - hopefully this thread will provide the clarity !

Comment: I don't know if I manage last file pointer, whether that will be right considering log rotations, file's trimmed or even deleted. I want to write the code myself and not add another layer with a third party.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Java 7, then you can use WatchService to notify you when a File inside of a directory changes. This is similar to interrupts and doesn't need continuous polling. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) for more details on WatchService. Otherwise you are better off with the polling method you already do.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Tailer:
http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html

This is Java implementation of "tail -f" Unix functionality.

Answer (score 1):

For detecting changes on files, or changes in any content inside directory, you can watch that directory for new content, modification of existing content and deletion of any existing content inside any directory.

See post: [Directory watching for changes in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998379/directory-watching-for-changes-in-java/14144798#14144798)